# Send new value to uitableviewcell and re-render

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, parameter-passing

I have UITableView that by default show 2 items in row. I need to rerender all tableview rows when I turn the phone to landscape mode and then display 3 items in row. I already have the logic of rendering 2 or 3 items and the number of rows that I need, but I don't know how to pass `isLandscaped` boolean that tells to cell how to render(landscape or portrait).

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BookshelfCell

    cell.changeOrientation(orientation: isLandscaped) // doesn't work
    cell.isLandscaped = self.isLandscaped // doesn't work
        
     if isLandscaped {
        
        cell.book1 = books[indexPath.row * 3] // Return for left side
        
        if (indexPath.row * 3 + 1) < books.count {
            cell.book2 = books[indexPath.row * 3 + 1] // Return for middle
        }
        
        if (indexPath.row * 3 + 2) < books.count {
            cell.book3 = books[indexPath.row * 3 + 2] // Return for right side
        }
        
    } else { // portrait
        cell.book1 = books[indexPath.row * 2] // Return for left side
        
        if (indexPath.row * 2 + 1) < books.count {
            cell.book2 = books[indexPath.row * 2 + 1] // return for right side
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Function that change `isLandscaped` book in ViewController(works ok):

```
@objc func rotated() {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        isLandscaped = true
    }
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {
        isLandscaped = false
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I tried the protocol delegate pattern, again I was able to send value to cell from VC, but not able to rerender the tableview with 3 items. I think the problem is that I always send `isLandscaped` bool to an existing cell, but I'm not rendering new cell with the new value. If I set 3 items(`isLandscaped = true`) in cell by default, it works fine. Maybe it's possible to initialize cell somehow? I also tried to call `cell.reloadInputViews()` and `tableview.reloadData()` just everywhere.. Also nothing.

I need to use uitableview and it should work on iOS 9.0, it's the rule of this task.
If someone has time to help I will appreciate it. I can send more code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function inside the BookshelfCell to handle setup

```
func setupCell(WithBooks books: [Books], Row row: Int, IsLandscape isLandscape: Bool)
```

have your UI code in this method

call it like

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BookshelfCell

    print("Setting up cell with. IsLandscape: \(self.isLandscaped)")
    cell.setupCell(WithBooks: books, Row: indexPath.row, IsLandscape: self.isLandscaped)
    
    return cell
}
```

a simple .reloadData() should be always enough te rerender the cells, there is no need to say them individually, directly.

Check if your self.isLandscape is always correct, print it to the console in cellForRow

Comment: I understand your logic and it works, but .reloadData() just doesn't do anything. If i open app in landscape mode - it shows 3 books. If in portrait - 2 books. But whenever I change mode/orientation of phone and call reloadData on tableview - it never changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [viewWillTransition(to:with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621466-viewwilltransition) method in your view controller. It will call this method each time when size of the view change so it detects orientation changes. So in your case you can call reloadData method there.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            // Logic for landscape
        } else {
            // Logic for portrait
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**
Also Apple sends notification named [orientationDidChangeNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620025-orientationdidchangenotification) when the orientation changed. So you can use notification center like that:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.rotated), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
}

deinit {
   NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)         
}

func rotated() {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        // Logic for landscape
    } else {
        // Logic for portrait
    }
}
```